# Comó cerrar un ciclo while con un punto que va al final de un texto en java?

Tags: java, while

Tengo este código y funciona bien pero el problema es que solo me cierra el ciclo cuando pongo un punto en lugar de cerrarlo al leer el punto final de la cadena de texto.

```
 String caracte;
 char le;
  Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

 System.out.println("Digite una cadena de texto y finalice con punto");
  while(!".".equals(caracte = sc.nextLine()))
 for (int i = 0; i < caracte.length(); i++) {
 le = caracte.charAt(i);
 System.out.println((int)le);
                  
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas comparando toda la linea con punto, prueba con

```
while(!(caracte = sc.nextLine()).endsWith(".")){
    for (int i = 0; i < caracte.length(); i++) {
         le = caracte.charAt(i);
    System.out.println((int)le);
}
```

Comment: Gracias!! Voy a intentar

Answer (score 0):

Para cerrar el ciclo while cuando se llega al final de la cadena de texto, podes modificar la condición en el ciclo while de la siguiente manera:

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    caracte = sc.nextLine();
    if (caracte.equals(".")) {
        break;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < caracte.length(); i++) {
        le = caracte.charAt(i);
        System.out.println((int)le);
    }
}
```

El método hasNextLine() devuelve verdadero si hay otra línea de entrada disponible y falso si se ha llegado al final de la entrada. Esto permite que el ciclo while continúe hasta que se alcance el final de la entrada. La instrucción break se usa para salir del ciclo cuando se alcanza el final de la entrada.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy  probar!!

Comment: Acabo de probarlo de esa manera pero entro en un ciclo infinito, no sé si tiene que ver que agreggué más código.

Comment: hasNextLine() devuelve verdadero si y solo si este escáner tiene otra línea de entrada. Si no tiene otra linea, no continúa con el while.

Comment: Con razón, gracias.